Makefile で複数の，Make が走るまで存在しないターゲットの書き方
あるウェブサイトに年ごとのページがあり，その年と URL の対応を記載した list.tsv があるとします．
2020    https://example.com/a.html
2019    https://example.com/b.html

この list.tsv は他のプログラムが生成していて，更新されることがあります（追記：必要なら更新も makefile に記述されていると考えて構いません）．どのような年のデータがあるかは， list.tsv を実際に見るまでは分かりません．（でも，あった年がなくなるとか，そういったややこしいことは考えなくてよいとします．）
このファイルに基づいて，URL にある html をダウンロードして pages/2020.html, pages/2019.html といった形で保存し，それらを generate-result.py を使って処理して，最終目標の result.txt を得られるとします．
wget にはファイルから URL を読み取る -i というオプションがありますが，これではファイル名の設定ができないようなので，TSV から html をダウンロードするやり方は
while read year url; do wget "$url" -O "pages/$year.html"; touch "pages/$year.html"; sleep 0.5; done < list.tsv

というような書き方をすることにしました．
さて，この処理を Makefile で書きたいです．pages/ の中にある html ファイルがすべて list.tsv より新しければ，そもそも wget が起こらないようにできるのではないかという想定です．
色々見ながら次のように書いてみました．
all: result.txt

pages/%.html: list.tsv | pages
    while read year url; do wget "$$url" -O "pages/$$year.html"; touch "pages/$$year.html"; sleep 0.5; done < ./$<

result.txt: pages/%.html
    echo $^
    # python generate-result.py $^

pages:
    mkdir -p $@

意味として正しいのかわからず，また，これで make をするとダウンロードはできるのですが，状況によらず wget が走るようになってしまっているようです．どのように書くのが正しいでしょうか？

% が思った展開はされておらず， pages/%.html というそのままのファイルを作ろうとして while read の行が動くので，pages/%.html が無い限りはいつも動くことになるっぽい…ことは朧げに理解しました． result.txt の依存先としての %.html も多分展開されていなくて，だからたまたま result.txt を作るために上の行が走っている？

GNU make のドキュメントから引用します。
Rule Syntax (GNU make)

4.2 Rule Syntax
In general, a rule looks like this:
targets : prerequisites
        recipe
        …

or like this:
targets : prerequisites ; recipe
        recipe
        …

The targets are file names, separated by spaces. Wildcard characters may be used (see Using Wildcard Characters in File Names) ...

Using Wildcard Characters in File Names

4.4 Using Wildcard Characters in File Names
A single file name can specify many files using wildcard characters. The wildcard characters in make are ‘*’, ‘?’ and ‘[…]’, the same as in the Bourne shell. For example, *.c specifies a list of all the files (in the working directory) whose names end in ‘.c’.

なので、pages/%.html ではなく pages/*.html にするとよいかと思います。

ありがとうございます！　(質問にする前には  VPATH の設定が干渉したりもしてうまく言っていなかったようです)　確かに動くのですが，新しい順に pages/a.html > list.tsv > pages/b.html のような状況のとき，はじめに出てくる a だけみて更新が行われない一方，pages/b.html > list.tsv > pages/a.html の順だと更新が行われるようで，なにか意図しない挙動をさせていないか少し気がかりです．
